# Service layer return object types

Tags: java, spring-boot, dao

You know that for an API project there are many patterns to retrieve and serve data to client. `Controller <-> Service <-> Dao` pattern is one of the these patterns.

Is it good to return any type of object from service layer or service layer return objects must be related entity?

For example, we have `User`, `UserService`, `UserDao`.
Should UserService return types be User  or any type of object is suitable?

Having logical operations in service layer force me to use other objects as return type.

What is the best practice for that case?

Comment: Generally Service will return what it meant to be. Like UserService returning  User or List<User>. You may optionally have a transformer which converts Entities to DTOs. Service will be responsible for fetching Entity or Entities and calling tansformer to convert it to DTOs

Comment: I agree with Armit on first part that the service returns domain models, while for the second it depends. Could be that I map to DTOs in application layer or if application is relatively small / compact I do that in the REST controller some async messaging controller (hexagonal architecture..)

Answer (score 3):

I've found that I need 3 types of objects to keep things manageable (I'm still in a battle trying to come up with a decent naming strategy). It's sometimes beneficial to have:

1. **Objects returned from your data layer** - These objects will be dictated by your data implementation. For example, they could change if you decide to store your data differently. Perhaps you decide to serialise an object and store it as JSON rather than storing it in a separate table, or you move from SQL to NOSQL.
2. **Objects returned from your domain layer** - These are application objects and should model your domain. They shouldn't contain anything that is specific to your data implementation.
3. **Objects sent to and from you API** - It's useful to have separate serialisation objects  to *shape* your API. It means you can tweak your API without having to touch the business logic. On some projects, I have multiple versions of the API objects for v1, v2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

The widely accepted practise involve the service to have all business logic in it and return the Data Transfer Object(DTO)/ Business Object like User in your case. The Service may call DAO, any other datasources to fetch the entities, and a mapper/converter util can be used to convert the entities to DTO objects.

The DTO objects returned from Service can be embedded in a ResponseEntity(In the case of Spring MVC) and returned from the controller.

This makes your application into 3 separated layers like web, service, dataaccess. This supports design principles like Separation of Concerns, Single Responsibility. This also makes your unit testing and code management easier.

Comment: Good explanation, thank you!  I'd like to read more suggestions from other  users.

Comment: Luckily this answer is not approved because I think it breaks the whole approach. Service layer SHOULD NOT have any idea how the DTO objects of the REST layer should look like. Because then if you change anything in the API you have to change the business logic, which has no sense. Return Business Objects in service layer, and convert it to API-specific objects in Controller. You can also abstract from entity objects in service layer, but in that case I would create more DDD-like structure of the project.

Comment: @Mejmo thansk for explanation, after months I realized your comment.